# How to create a new ExeConfigurationFileMap instance in Powershell?

Tags: reflection, powershell

I have the following Powershell code:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Configuration

[ExeConfigurationFileMap] $configMap = New-Object ExeConfigurationFileMap
```

All I want to do is create a new instance of `ExeConfigurationFileMap`, but each and every way I try, PS keeps telling me that it cannot find the type `ExeConfigurationFileMap` and that I should check the type's assembly is loaded into memory.

I've tried different ways of loading the System.Configuration assembly into memory, but the code still fails to work.

Could someone please assist me with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
$configMap = New-Object -TypeName System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap
```

Comment: Argh pants, I think I see what I did wrong. I was not using the fully qualified path for the type, and in situations where I did, I had square brackets eg -TypeName [blah] which was wrong. Cheers for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full type name e.g.:

```
New-Object System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap
```

Technically you don't have to provide the `System.` because PowerShell will prepend that if it fails to find the specified type.

Comment: Weird, SO is usually pretty good about showing a banner when an answer has been posted to the current question. Go figure.